# How to index a date without day & time in Apache Solr

Tags: search, indexing, solr, lucene, solrj

In my database the dates are like `1973-01`. They are stored as string value. If  I have to index this using Apache Solr then how would I do it.

I have written the below in my schema.xml:

`<field name="pubdate" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />`

I have also changed all the dates like `1973-01Z`. But I am still getting an error:

`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Invalid Date in Date Math String:'1973-01Z'`

I believe Solr only accepts date like `1995-12-31T23:59:59Z`

Can anyone help?

Comment: You could also use `string` type instead of `tdate`

Comment: If I do so then can I search  or sort based on date? @HectorCorrea

Answer (score 1):

In solrconfig.xml you can define the date formats your update request handler can process inside an updateRequestProcessorChain with the help of a  ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory:

```
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="parse-field-types">
    <processor class="solr.RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseBooleanFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseLongFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseDoubleFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <!-- A default time zone name or offset may optionally be specified for those 
           dates that don't include an explicit zone/offset.
      -->
      <str name="defaultTimeZone">Europe/Berlin</str>
      <arr name="format">
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC</str>
      </arr>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Then you have to connect the updateRequestProcessorChain with the update request handler

```
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">parse-field-types</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Maybe you can define a format here that is working for you.